# What is protect code used for?

Tags: orders, api, rest-api

We're working on a project where we're replacing our existing web store with a custom Magento integration.

We need a way for a guest customer to retrieve information about their order by following a unique URL that can't just be guessed from the sequential order number (i.e. we need a unique secret ID for an order).

An order fetched from the API contains a field named `protect_code`, which at first glance seems to be doing exactly this.

Do we assume correctly that the protect code can safely be used for this use case? The official docs are extremely scarce regarding this field, so does anyone know what its official purpose actually is?

Comment: Slightly different request, but same mechanism being mentioned. Take a look, maybe it helps - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189667/how-reorder-verifies-guest-and-logged-in-user/189705#189705

Comment: Maybe this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987180/1119601) helps.